# Qt - Making a panel that overlaps a QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qlayout

I am trying to make a panel that shows some data, that gets added when I press a button. I will explain it trough these images:

this would be the initial state of the app, a window with a QGraphicsView[image: This would be the initial state of the app]

if I click "Help" it should display a window above it that never goes out of focus[image]

I looked into using QDockWidget, but that just creates a panel next to it, that that's not what I Want. If anyone knows how to do this, I would be very grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set children widgets in your QGraphicsView and consider it like a regular QWidget:

```
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->show();

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Show label");
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("Foobar");
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(view);
    layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    layout->addWidget(label);
    label->hide();
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, label, &QLabel::show);
    return app.exec();
```

The label will be visible in the QGraphicsView when you click on the button.

You can also embed a widget in your scene with `QGraphicsProxyWidget` class:

```
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    scene->addItem(new QGraphicsRectItem(500, 500, 50, 50));
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->show();

    QWidget* w = new QWidget();
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();


    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Show label");
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("Foobar");
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(w);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    layout->addWidget(label);
    layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop);
    label->hide();
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, label, &QLabel::show);

    proxy->setWidget(w);
    scene->addItem(proxy);
    return app.exec();
```

Comment: thanks, could i replace the label with a qgraphicsview?

Comment: You can replace the label by any QWidget. But, in this case, you should handle QGraphicsObject/item in your main view. The second QGraphicsView is useless.

Comment: well i want to display like a legend type thing, where i have images and labels next to them, should i use a qtableview?

Comment: QTableView is used to display data from a model. You should use a widget with a layout for that.